# VSS 6.0 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sourcesafe-6.0

Just started a new job and we currently use Source Safe 6.0.  We recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2005 to 2010 and now I can't get it to integrate with Source Safe.

Is it even possible to integrate VS 2010 with VSS 6.0?

Thanks

Comment: Whatever the true answer is, please try to make managers believe that it's not possible so they approve moving to TFS/Subversion/Anything but VSS really

Answer (score 0):

Sure, make sure you install the latest VSS version. I think it's this one: [Visual SourceSafe 2005 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8a1a68d8-db11-417c-91ad-02aab484776b&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

We use it without any big problems. @Dyppl: not so negative about VSS. We switched from VS2008 to VS2010 without a problem. Did you went into the preferences for VS2010 to select your default source control provider? There are some settings to be made. Good luck.